# Real Time Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

All -

I have currently have a POC WPF project which works end to end. The application simulates real-time market data being published through a library (Publisher) and my WPF client is Subscriber (has the handler method). It uses Custom Events to publish data.

Question I have is this:

1) I want to implement Producer Consumer - so my handler doesn't pull the data into Observable  Collection directly.

2) I precisely know how to implement Producer/Consumer C# snippets (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601.aspx) but wanted to more understand how this will fit in my current architecture. Here is a diagram

3) Can anybody help me out with code approach, links etc.

[image]

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindow_VM : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Properties
    public myCommand SbmtCmd { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<StockModel> stocks { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private readonly Dispatcher currentDispatcher;
    #endregion

    public MainWindow_VM()
    {
        SbmtCmd = new myCommand(mySbmtCmdExecute, myCanSbmtCmdExecute);
        currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        stocks = new ObservableCollection<StockModel>();
    }

    private void mySbmtCmdExecute(object parameter)
    {
        MarketDataProvider p = new MarketDataProvider();
        p.OnMarketData += new EventHandler<MarketDataEventArgs>(handlermethod);     
        p.GenerateMarketData();
    }

    private bool myCanSbmtCmdExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }


    // Subscriber method which will be called when the publisher raises an event 

    private void handlermethod(object sender, MarketDataEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Stock s in e.updatedstk)
        {
            StockModel sm = new StockModel();

            sm.symbol = s.symbol;
            sm.bidprice = s.bidprice;
            sm.askprice = s.askprice;
            sm.lastprice = s.lastprice;

            currentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
            {
                if (sm != null)
                {
                    if (stocks.Any(x => x.symbol == sm.symbol))
                    {
                        var found = stocks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.symbol == sm.symbol);
                        int i = stocks.IndexOf(found);
                        stocks[i] = sm;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stocks.Add(sm);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611

Comment: Thanks Jodha - unfortunately I have environment limitations on using .Net 3.5 and hence need to solve this using traditional C# approaches

Comment: Then you can't use DataFlow either. It's available only in .NET 4 and above, while Reactive Extensions are available for 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some projects with market feeds and your chart looks fine conceptually.  To avoid scalability issues, or to design proactively against scalability issues, you can consider making your producer/consumer box have multiple instances to accommodate multiple feeds and/or multiple instruments within the feed. If, for example, a given market becomes densely volatile, you don't want all the other instruments starved for data.

Also, some people like to switch feeds for a given instrument based upon arbitrary criteria, like getting YEN from London until the gold fix, and then switching to NYC, and then again switching to Tokyo.

The other thing I can mention is for the arrow going out of the producer/consumer box to pass POCO DTO's only.  It adds to the value of your application and also makes isolation testing a lot easier.

Testing off live feeds (or even simulated feeds) is scant because they don't capture all the conditions that need to be tested before an app is deployable.

Finally I would mention that the producer/consumer pattern was implemented starting in .NET 4.0 with the System.Collections.Concurrent name space...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx  I have been using these classes in production and they really cut through the need to test a home-grown design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a UI toolkit called [ReactiveTables](https://bitbucket.org/mendelmonteiro/reactivetables) which allows you to create live tables which can be joined, filtered, extended with calculated columns and then bound to WPF controls. The tables expose an IObservable interface and have been designed for performance.

You can hook the tables up directly to your producer/consumer implementation and then bind them to your views.  The tables will notify on changes to individual cells and there is a helper class for translating this into INotifyPropertyChanged events.

On the receiving side there are classes which can throttle updates to the UI tables and marshal form your data threads to the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks Slugart - am checking this out