# Excel as real time data source in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm creating .NET Framework 4.5 based Window application.

The requirement is to bind excel to C# application. And whenever the data in excel changes (which will change frequently from Trading markets), the same should get sync(or updated) in Window application.

While researching for solution I thought following as possible answer -

**(1) Opposite of RTD Server in Excel**

Excel initiate RTD Server for getting data from real time data source by IRTDUpdatEvent. Is there any mechanism that excel sends updated or changed data to other application?

**(2) Producer-Consumer pattern**

I think the possible strong solution can be designing application in this pattern. Pattern link at [Producer Consumer workfow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601.aspx). Even a user asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451531/real-time-data-binding).

But I am not experienced with this pattern. So do you have suggestion for me that it will work or not.

**(3) DevExpress RealTimeSource**

I am planning for using RealTimeSource for binding to gridview. But I fear that I had to read excel file each second, load data into dataset or datatable. And then reflect in application.

So here is what I'm looking for -

1. Make Excel as real time data source. Because we would be getting updated data in excel file.
2. An optimize and extremely fast way to sync data from Excel.

I'm interested in knowing all possible type of solution, hint or advice for same. Or if you have any guidance or recommendation for me, please do let me know.

Comment: This is a VB-looking doc but has some good starting places for you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Comment: @kingdango I am aware of reading data from excel file by the way suggested in link. I am looking for making excel as real time data source.

Comment: I think it may be easier to simply detect if the file was modified and then pull data from file when change is detected.

Comment: @V.S.Saini Have you considered what you're trying to do?  When you say "realtime" it could mean a lot of things.  Probably what you want is real-time synchronization (guessing that's what you mean).  But consider the fact that SQL isn't "realtime" by default, you have to setup some way to detect changes and synchronize.  If you're looking for something that "does it for you" I don't think such a thing exists.

Comment: @kingdango Thanks for taking time to answer. I agree with you fully. SQL have triggers that alert attached application for changes. And so I am assuming there might be something in excel too. That will send alert to C# application to retrieve data.

Comment: The solution would be to make Excel behave as RTD Server and the application to behave as RTD Client. **Because Excel can behave both as RTD Server and RTD Client**. I had not implemented solution for it as project get closed due to delay. But it is worthy mentioning here, so that other can benefit from it.